# Teaser display showing on full node content page

Tags: views, theming, nodes

as my title says my teaser display had been showing up on the full content page of my nodes and we can't seem to figure out "Why".

The content type has 2 views and 2 blocks.

- One view with all
- One view with all of one author
- One block with the newest 3
- One block with the 3 most popular.

It started with one node that showed the teaser instead of the content? Then all the nodes in the blocks started doing this. 
And now all the nodes show the teaser instead of the content page.
Even when accessing it through: Admin > sturcture > content.

This is what the content page used to look like
[image]

This is what the view page looks like[image]

And this is what the content page NOW looks like
[image]

UPDATE: So I found out that when I remove the blocks out of the regions my content shows normal. When the Two blocks are IN a region the content page of ALL is messed up. Still don't know why.

UPDATE2: So I a part the problem.

The block view of the 3 most popular tours didn't have a restricted amount of items per page.

I noticed that when I removed the block out of the regions the content pages where fixed.

So I started to look at that block and that was the only thing that didn't fit. So I changed it to limited 3 items per page. And added the block again to the region.

Now the content that is shown in the blocks, when clicking them they still show a teaser on the content page. Event when accessing them through the view or admin panel.